# What is correct way of setting up phonegap project?

Tags: android, cordova

I have setup phonegap for android on my machine.I have searched over net and come with two different solutions for starting android project in phonegap

**(1) Using Command Line Tool for creating project**

phonegap create myFirstApp

cd myFirstApp

and then importing project in eclipse

**(2) Directly from eclipse IDE**

Choose New > Android Project and then filling necessary information

Now question is which should I use, and which one is better for starting phonegap project for android?

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously, no single answer. You can use any, whatever you are interested in. Also, you can write your entire code in the `www` folder and may not open Eclipse **at all**.

Personally, I connect my android phone with USB debugging on, and whenever I feel like testing my app, I type in the command in the terminal

```
$ cordova run android
```

If you have configured a Virtual Machine, it will start the virtual machine or the app is installed directly on my device.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is

3) Using Command Line Tool for creating project

phonegap create myFirstApp

cd myFirstApp

Use any editor to edit the www folder (brackets, sublime)

Use the CLI to run, build, etc.

Forget about eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Documentation the best way is as follows:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cd hello
```

Then to add platforms:

```
 $ cordova platform add ios
 $ cordova platform add amazon-fireos
 $ cordova platform add android
 $ cordova platform add blackberry10
 $ cordova platform add firefoxos
```

And run the app

```
$ cordova emulate ios
```

And build the app

```
$ cordova build ios
```